# Return Max Value in Range of Mixed Data Types

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel worksheet row cells contain a mixed collection of data types -- numbers, alphas, and errors (e.g., #REF!). I want to pass this range to a function which finds the max number only and ignores the alphas and errors. My code:

```
Public Function getRangeMax(passedRange As range) As Single
'validate entries in passed range as numbers or skip
'return max from validated numbers

Dim i As Integer, arryLength As Integer
Dim arry()

getRangeMax = 0

arry() = passedRange
arryLength = UBound(arry) - LBound(arry)

For i = 0 To arryLength
    On Error Resume Next
    If arry(i).value > getRangeMax Then
        getRangeMax = arry(i).value
    End If
Next i

'getRangeMax = Application.Max(passedRange)

End Function
```

The function call is: =getRangeMax(C35:I35). The data in that particular range of cells is: dB, 456.00, #REF!, 12. I would expect the code to ignore the dB and #REF! entries and return the maximum number, which in this case is 456.00. Instead, the function returns 0.00. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the elements of your array. Don't think it's holding what you think it is. Might want to do a `for each c in passedRange` to store into array.

Comment: Once you store the Range into array in memory, it's a multi dimensional array. In your case it will be `arry(1 To UBound(arry), 1 To 1)`.

Comment: @PatricK Would be correct if passed a range from a single column.  OP is passing `C35:I35` so the second dimension varies

Comment: Pardon me, somehow I was reading it as `C35:C135`... the `C35:I35` can be accessed by `arry(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(Application.Transpose(arry)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains multiple errors, all hidden from you by the always active `On Error Resume Next`

Here's your code refactored to fix the errors and with an alternative type check

```
Public Function getRangeMax(passedRange As Range) As Double
'validate entries in passed range as numbers or skip
'return max from validated numbers

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim arry()

    getRangeMax = 0
    arry() = passedRange

    For i = 1 To UBound(arry, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arry, 2)
        item = arry(i, j)
        If VarType(item) = vbDouble Then
            If item > getRangeMax Then
                getRangeMax = item
            End If
        End If
    Next j, i
End Function
```

Note:
Using `VarType` to test for valid items to process will result in any cells that are Text but *look like* numbers to be ignored.
Using `IsNummeric` to test for valid items to process will result in any cells that are Text but *look like* numbers to be converted to numbers and included in the test.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Function Rng_Max_Get(rTrg As Range) As Double
Dim aTrg As Variant, vItm As Variant, blTrg As Boolean
    aTrg = rTrg.Value2
    For Each vItm In aTrg
        If IsNumeric(vItm) Then
            If vItm <> Empty Then
                If blTrg Then
                    If vItm > Rng_Max_Get Then Rng_Max_Get = vItm
                Else
                    blTrg = True
                    Rng_Max_Get = vItm
    End If: End If: End If: Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inputting a rectangular Range, you can use the `.Rows.Count` and `.Columns.Count` instead of deriving from **UBound**. Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Function getRangeMax(passedRange As Range) As Double
    'validate entries in passed range as numbers or skip
    'return max from validated numbers

    Dim lRows As Long, lCols As Long, lR As Long, lC As Long
    Dim uValue As Double, uMax As Double
    Dim arry() As Variant

    arry = passedRange
    lRows = passedRange.Rows.Count
    lCols = passedRange.Columns.Count
    uMax = 0
    For lR = 1 To lRows
        For lC = 1 To lCols
            If IsNumeric(arry(lR, lC)) Then
                uValue = CDbl(arry(lR, lC))
                If uValue > uMax Then uMax = uValue
            End If
        Next
    Next
    getRangeMax = uMax
End Function
```

Comment: Using `UBound` is significantly faster than `Range.Rows/Columns.Count`